# Suggest some methods for measuring AC current

Tags: sensor

I need to find a method of doing so without consuming much space in PCB like in the case of current transformers. The circuit must be able to measure upto 15A of AC current(RMS).

Answer (score 5):

If you have space on the board for an 8-pin SOIC, you can use the [Allegro ACS712x20](http://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/Files/Datasheets/ACS712-Datasheet.ashx) for current sensing.

It is a Hall-effect-based linear current sensor IC that can directly sense up to 20 Amperes, bidirectional current, with no additional components (current transformers etc) required.

It has 2.1 kVRMS minimum isolation voltage between sense line and signal output, and generates an analog signal proportional to magnitude and direction of sensed current. Resistance of the sensing path is 1.2 milliOhm. No external shunt resistor is required.

More information [on the Allegro site](http://www.allegromicro.com/Products/Current-Sensor-ICs/Zero-To-Fifty-Amp-Integrated-Conductor-Sensor-ICs/ACS712.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, MichaelKaras :-) I always make that mistake with Allegro parts!

Comment: Using the proposed ACS712x20 is a great solution. The user should be fully aware of the safety requirements needed when designing a circuit board with on-board AC connections. The original question did not specify the working voltage of the circuit being monitored but if it is mains voltage connected then there are multiple considerations to take into consideration. These include minimum clearance between the measured circuit and the low voltage section of the circuit board. Be aware that these requirements do not fit on the circuit board solely in the space consumed by a mere 8-pin SOIC.